# C# UI Automation API with multiple virtual desktops on Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, ui-automation

Warning, I'm coming into this problem as someone who had never used C# before a couple of days ago...

I'm trying to write a "simple" program that scrapes text from a targeted window and displays it on a 2x20 VFD display. I've learned about using the Microsoft UI Automation API, and have had some success in using it to accomplish my goal.

However, if the target window is on a *different virtual desktop* it seems that using TreeWalker on the AutomationElement.RootElement will not find the target.

The code I'm using now to get my target window (while it's on the same virtual desktop):

```
    public static AutomationElementCollection FindByMultipleConditions(AutomationElement anElement)
    {
        if (anElement == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        Condition conditions = new AndCondition(
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Pane),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsContentElementProperty, true),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsControlElementProperty, true),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsKeyboardFocusableProperty, false),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ClassNameProperty, "Chrome_WidgetWin_0")
            );
        AutomationElementCollection elementCollection =
            anElement.FindAll(TreeScope.Children, conditions);
        return elementCollection;
    }
```

An AutomationElement.RootElement is passed to this method, and this seems to be granular enough to always target the specific window I'm interested in, but it returns nothing if my target window is moved to a different virtual desktop.

Is this a limitation of using the UI Automation API to accomplish my task? Is there a way to iterate through each virtual desktop while searching for my target window or should I try a different way of approaching this?

Thanks!

Comment: First I heard of it, but not inconceivable.  Just try this with another known-good tool, use the Inspect.exe SDK utility and tell us what you see happening.  [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/troubleshoot/winautomation/process-development-tips/ui-automation/using-inspect-exe-to-access-ui-elements-winautomation-is-not-able-to-see).

Comment: The thing that sticks out to me is that the top of the tree in inspect.exe is "Desktop 3" pane, where the target window currently is. What do you mean by another known-good tool? It seems that each virtual desktop is its own "tree" as far as the UI Automation API is concerned...

Comment: You should probably implement [IVirtualDesktopManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ivirtualdesktopmanager) and use its `::MoveWindowToDesktop()` to enumerate Top Level Windows in the current VDesktop.

Comment: Right. Free sample C# code here: [VirtualDesktop - GitHub](https://github.com/MScholtes/VirtualDesktop)

Comment: If you *are* talking about Windows 10 new virtual desktop feature and not confusing desktop and monitors, UIAutomation's root node corresponds to the current virtual desktop, so your UIA app must run in the same desktop as the automated app.

Comment: So if I'm understanding everything correctly, my options are to either:

A) Run my program on the same Windows 10 virtual desktop as my target application window

B) Use VirtualDesktop to move my program to a different virtual desktop if my target application is not found on the current virtual desktop; rinse and repeat until target application is found 

Is that about it? I read some more on the UI Automation API and the .RootElement method only appears to return the *current* virtual desktop as the top of the logical tree.

I'll have a go using VirtualDesktop to try this out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The managed "System.Windows.Automation" library is old and predates multiple desktops being implemented in Windows as far as I know.

You should try to use the new automation api introduced in Windows 8. Sadly it's not managed, but there is great library called [FlaUI](https://github.com/FlaUI/FlaUI) that makes it as easy to use as the managed library (be sure to use FlaUI.UIA3 not FlaUI.UIA2 when using it to use the new api).

If you don't want a full library then there is a [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Interop.UIAutomationClient) wrapper for the new com api (from the same guys behind FlaUI I think).

Good luck.